# How to hide background for ::cue pseudo-element on Safari?

Tags: css, html, safari

I'm trying to hide captions on a video element:

[image: captions without css]

I'm using the following css:

`video::cue {
  visibility: hidden;
}`

It works fine in Chrome, but on Safari it only hides the text, and still renders the caption background, like this:

[image: captions with visibility: hidden]

I tried adding `background: none` as well, but there's no change.
How else can I hide the captions on Safari, besides modifying the text track list programmatically? Could this be a Safari bug?

Comment: `background-color` seems to be ignored. Setting `font-size: 0px` shrinks the "bubble" into a very small circle, but it still doesn't go away.

Comment: add some code or fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hsoLnj9L/1/

I am running into this same issue as well. I would like to update the background-color for the VTT subs, but seems that this property has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is already mentioned here: [Hiding a video text track with Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710074/hiding-a-video-text-track-with-safari). That is, if what you're trying to do is not display your captions directly in the video anyway, just use the track kind "metadata". In my case:

```
<track default label="English" kind="metadata" srclang="en" src="../static/captions/mexicocity_en.vtt" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to target the parent element of video::cue and hide it. By the way display:none can also be used for hiding though I am not sure