# Hiding a video text track with Safari

Tags: javascript, css, video

Using this method works on Firefox/Chrome but not with Safari

```
let videoElement = document.querySelector(`#my-video`);
let track = videoElement.textTracks[0];
track.mode = 'hidden';
```

I have also tried the `::cue` css selector

```
::cue {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This hides the text itself but not the semi-transparent black background.

I need to keep the text track as I am rendering the content elswhere, but I don't want it repeated over the video.

Is there a way to do this, have I missed something?

Comment: So you don't want this to be user selectable - toggled?

Comment: Not in this instance no, I'm just using the text track as a way to sync messages displayed elsewhere to the video.

Comment: You've done it correctly. I'm perplexed. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: How many track elements are you using? Just one?

Comment: Yes, just one — though I am planning to add another language potentially.

Comment: For the example do you have a preference of which service to use?

Comment: Nope. You pick...I'll conform ;-)

Comment: Your S3 instance doesn't recognize the .vtt MIME type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Randy—I've deleted my codepen because it is a WIP and the answer below resolved it, but want to say I really appreciate the effort you made it's very much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't realize you had no intent of displaying - metadata makes perfect sense. Sorry I didn't see that sooner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your track `kind` to `metadata`.

Since that's how you're using the track anyway, this would be the most appropriate.  As a bonus, tracks of this `kind` are not displayed to the user so there's nothing else to do.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you :)